# Insert in sqlite python doesn't change table

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm create simple class for SQLite datadase and when I'm insert new row table doesn't change.

DB.py

```
import sqlite3

class DB:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.db = sqlite3.connect('passwods.db')
        self.c = self.db.cursor()
        self.c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS passwords (name, value)')

    def insert(self, alias, cipher):
        column = (alias, cipher)
        self.c.execute('INSERT INTO passwords (name, value) VALUES (?,?)',  column)
        self.db.commit()

    def get(self, alias):
        pk = (alias,)
        self.c.execute('SELECT * FROM passwords WHERE name=?', pk) 

    def getAll(self):
        self.c.execute('SELECT * FROM passwords')
```

Interactive shell

```
>>> from DB import DB
>>> db = DB()
>>> db.insert('firstName', 'firstValue')
>>> print(db.getAll())
None
>>>
```

Comment: You need to commit when you change data.

Comment: exactly as polku says. for database "transactions" other than queries, you have to use the `commit()` after the `execute()`. In your case, it would probably be `self.db.commit()` at the end of the `insert` function

Comment: I'm added commit() , but it's still doesn't work

Comment: >>> from DB import DB
>>> db = DB()
>>> db.insert('firstName', 'firstValue')
>>> print(DB().getAll())
None
>>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `getAll` has no return statement. If you add it, you can see that the table actually changes:

```
def getAll(self):
    self.c.execute("SELECT * FROM passwords")
    return self.c.fetchall()
```

Comment: Thank! Maybe I need some break